# Is filmic log used for better color grading?

Tags: rendering

I know it might sound like a stupid question, but I was wondering what is the best workflow for color grading and overall post-production using blender. When I work with video footage or photos I usually start with log footage, though I'm not sure if it is the correct way to go with blender, or any rendering software overall. Does anyone have insights on the topic?

Comment: It is not a stupid question. If you are used to grading log footage, then just save the images as log in blender.